# REST Web Service GET method can persist entity

Tags: java, rest, jpa, service, get

In my attempt to study REST web services, using NetBeans 8.2, I've created one over an entity automatically created from the supplied *sample* database.

While testing the URI for the method find (annotated @GET), I am attempting to obfuscate or mask one of the properties of the entity I'm retrieving, by changing it after it was retrieved from the database.

Here is the find method changed:

```
@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Manufacturer find(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
    Manufacturer mfg = super.find(id);

    // seems like this line merges the entity in the database. Why?! 
    mfg.setAddressline2("Suite ABC"); 

    return mfg; 
    // return super.find(id); -- this line would prove the obvious that somehow the entity was merged
}
```

The value of Addressline2 in the database before invoking find(id), is something like "Suite 100".

To test the find I use this URL on the browser:

http://localhost:8080/REST01/rest/manufacturers/19985678 where 19985678 is the value of the PK of the table.

The output is:

```
<manufacturer>
<addressline1>5 81st Street</addressline1>
<addressline2>**Suite ABC**</addressline2>
<city>Mountain View</city>
<email>happysearching@example.com</email>
<fax>408-555-0103</fax>
<manufacturerId>19985678</manufacturerId>
<name>Happy End Searching</name>
<phone>650-555-0102</phone>
<rep>John Snow</rep>
<state>CA</state>
<zip>94043</zip>
</manufacturer>
```

To my surprise, I see the value in the database changed to the modified value - Suite ABC - when I only invoke a GET method.

I've tried this over an Oracle database and with GlassFish and WebLogic servers. The symptom is consistent.

Here is the persistence configuration, nothing added to the vanilla xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.1" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence 
 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="REST01PU" transaction-type="JTA">
<jta-data-source>jdbc/sample</jta-data-source>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties/>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Could someone explain the mechanism at play that persists the entity behind the scene?

Thank you very much,

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database is affected because when you invoke `Manufacturer mfg = super.find(id);`
the `mfg` object becomes a managed object by the Entity Manager. This means that any direct change will be reflected in the database.

There are ways to disconect the entity. For example you can invoke super.detach(mfg) (I presuming that in super exists Entity Manager methods access)

Comment: Thank you, Henrique.

I've never tried changing an EntityManager found object before, and this took me by surprise as I assumed the @GET would guarantee detachment.

... tunnel vision on my part, I guess.

Cheers!

Comment: Also, going back to basics, once found, the entity is in managed state, which ensures persistence. Totally overlooked.